# Efficiently handling backbone pushState routes server-side?

Tags: backbone.js, pushstate

I have Backbone working with pushState. It's very nice, but now I understand that I should support loading the app from any route that backbone uses. For example, if somebody enters a backboen route manually to their browser, the server should respond to that and render the page and then let backbone take over.

What I am wondering, is what is the most efficient way to handle it? Backbone recommends also bootstrapping data on initial page load to reduce ajax requests. Should I only try to bootstrap data that is necessary for that particular view or should I try to bootstrap basic collections (for example: users, settings, documents, etc)?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part of your question, you could just specify a callback route (which matches everything and gives the homepage) so the user never gets a 404 (don't use that when developing the app though, it could give you some hard times debugging it if you have a real 404 when making a call to the server).

For the second one, I'd say it depends on the amounts of data you need. I'm personally developing a modular application, and unfortunately can't really bootstrap anything. I'd say it's just some advice.